# How to use Org Capture to add a task *and* automatically add parent's property

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I'm trying to create an `org-capture` template that creates a task *and* (important part) automatically adds a parent's property to this new task. I'm comfortable creating new `capture` templates--I'm just unsure of the latter part.

If it matters I'm trying to "inherit" the `CATEGORY` property to my new tasks.

Also, I prefer not to use property inheritance if I can help it. The documentation is very clear that this can adversely affect performance.

Comment: The `CATEGORY` property (and a few others) is always [inherited](http://orgmode.org/manual/Property-inheritance.html).

Comment: @erikstokes, going off of [an excerpt from the Org Mode manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Property-inheritance.html "https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Property-inheritance.html") it was my impression that the behavior you described only occurs while in `org-agenda` mode. I'd like to physically assign the parent `CATEGORY` to new child tasks (preferably through `org-capture`). I'm ignorant to possible functions that can read parent properties, which is what I believe I need in this case.

Comment: The usual way to see the category is with `org-get-category` which does inheritance. You could also use `org-entry-get`.  However putting these into a capture template in the obvious way doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can get the properties from the "parent" in a tree.  Does this help you with what you're trying to achieve?

```el
* foo  
  :PROPERTIES:
  :CATEGORY: awesome
  :END:
** bar 
Run commands like these
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(org-set-property "CATEGORY"
          (save-excursion (org-up-heading-safe)
                  (org-entry-get (point) "CATEGORY")))
#+END_SRC
*** baz 
http://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-property-API.html
```

Comment: This looks like it will do exactly what I need it to. I'll test it soon and get back. Thanks for your help!